# VimPlugin: Scroll autocomplete suggestion in Visual Studio without arrows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vim, autocomplete, visual-assist

Is possible to configure `Vim plugin` for `VisualStudio` to let you scroll the VisualAssistX's context menu showing autocomplete options without using arrows keys?

I found this [bug](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/908) but those shortcut don't work for me. It seems to scroll through and alternative list of auto-complete suggestions, but nothing related to what VS and/or visual assist would suggest.

Note:
I am working on a `c++` environment with `VS2015` and `VisualAssistX`.